# How to grant permission to a user to manage users and groups and prevent the same user to import and export work item types in TFS

Tags: tfs

How to grant permission to a user to manage users and groups and prevent the same user to import and export work item types in TFS. if i added the user to project admin group the user would be able to do both of the mentioned tasks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no any way to do it out of the box.
As you can see, "Project Admnistrators" group is hardcoded project group, which you cannot remove or manage it permissions. TFS system have no special permission to deny import/export workitem types. "Project Administrators" members can modify WITD by default.

But there is a workaround.
First of all you will need to create a custom group (for example: "PM"), grand the same permissions for it (like "Project Administrators" already have) and move all PM users from "Project Administrators" to the new group. After that, members of this group cannot modify the project templates.

Then you have to prevent the addition of any user to the "Project Administrators" group.
You can use this command for it:

```
TFSSecurity.exe /a+ Server FrameworkGlobalSecurity GenericRead n:"[PROJECT]\Project Administrators" DENY /collection:http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection
```

Now each user in "[PROJECT]\Project Administrators" group will lose the whole access to the TFS Server.
Of course, you must inform the users about that.

Comment: how the new group members will be able to manage team project security "manage users and groups"?

Comment: You will need to allow "Edit project-level information" permission for this group.

Comment: I tried here, I created the new group, moved all users, executed the command to DENY, but still the user can change the workitems, but can't access the project web access. Still will be possible for the user to change the template this way.